# Cross Platform Google+ Login API keys when building a Codename One Application

Tags: java, google-plus, codenameone

I'm building a game which can connect to Google+ and can be run an Windows (for testing), Android and iOS. Google has an "api-key" for different platforms. For example, api-key for Browser, Android or iOS. So I currently have to use the below code to detect the running platform to set the api-key correctly.

```
    if (Display.getInstance().isSimulator())
        req.addArgumentNoEncoding("key", apiKeyBrowser);
    else if (Display.getInstance().isPureTouch())
        req.addArgumentNoEncoding("key", apiKeyAndroid);
    else
        req.addArgumentNoEncoding("key", apiKeyiOS);
```

If there is a "keys setting" panel for each platform (in "each platform" node tree in the project properties dialog), I just need put the "api-key" key with correct platform value. And in code, the just need to have a code like this:

```
    req.addArgumentNoEncoding("key", Registry.getKeyValue("api-key"));
```

The Registry is a special class which [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) created it during building the application for each platform. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google+ login API is implemented natively by Codename One and these separate API keys are for the native binding.

In the code you should always use the web version of the keys as this is only used for the simulator and desktop ports where web is used. In the build hints you need to supply the other keys appropriately. See https://www.codenameone.com/google-login.html for the full details.